# Writing a fast 3d matrix and vector library in cython

Tags: python, cython

As part of rewriting my game engine in cython, I am trying to improve the performance of my python+numpy classes for matrix and vector math as this was one of the major bottlenecks I had run into previously. This group of modules had defined classes for types such as `Vector2/3/4`, `Matrix2/3/4`, and `Quaternion`.

Taking a page from the [glMatrix javascript library](http://glmatrix.net/), I thought that one thing I could do this time around is switch away from a class-based system to a module with just a bunch of math functions to reduce more overhead. That way, instead of returning a new object every time I, say, added two vectors together, I would not have to construct a custom object.

To test this out, I wrote a benchmark demo for creating two `Vec2` objects `a` and `b` summing them component-wise to get a `Vec2` object `out`. The code for this is broken down into a `main.py` that does the timing, a `vec2.pyx` for the cython code, and a `pyvec2.py` for the python code. Here is the code for each of those components:

**main.py**

```
import time
import array
import math3d.vec2 as vec2
import math3d.pyvec2 as pyvec2

def test(n, func, param_list):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        func(*param_list)
    end = time.time()
    print func, end-start

test(1000000, pyvec2.pyadd, [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
test(1000000, pyvec2.pyadd2, [[0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
test(1000000, vec2.add, [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
test(1000000, vec2.add2, [array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add3, [array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add4, [array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add5, [[0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
test(1000000, vec2.add6, [array.array("f", [0, 0]), array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add7, [array.array("f", [0, 0]), array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add8, [array.array("f", [0, 0]), array.array("f", [1, 2]), array.array("f", [3, 4])])
test(1000000, vec2.add9, [[0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

**vec2.pyx**

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cpython cimport array
import array

def add(list a, list b):
    cdef float[2] out = [0, 0]
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add2(float[:] a, float[:] b):
    cdef float[2] out = [0, 0]
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add3(array.array a, array.array b):
    cdef float[2] out = [0, 0]
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add4(array.array a, array.array b):
    cdef array.array out = array.array("f", [0, 0])
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add5(list out, list a, list b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add6(float[:] out, float[:] a, float[:] b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add7(array.array out, array.array a, array.array b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add8(array.array out, array.array a, array.array b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out

def add9(out, a, b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out
```

**pyvec2.py**

```
def pyadd(a, b):
    out = [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]]

def pyadd2(out, a, b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out
```

Here the results after running `main.py`:

```
<function pyadd at 0x0000000003354828> 0.380000114441
<function pyadd2 at 0x0000000003354908> 0.31299996376
<built-in function add> 0.261000156403
<built-in function add2> 0.680999994278
<built-in function add3> 0.268000125885
<built-in function add4> 0.601000070572
<built-in function add5> 0.144999980927
<built-in function add6> 1.06299996376
<built-in function add7> 0.241000175476
<built-in function add8> 0.237999916077
<built-in function add9> 0.141000032425
```

From this, it looks like just using python lists are faster than typed arrays! Furthermore, just blindly compiling my python function without typing into cython yielded the best results! It looks like a significant portion of the time spent executing the code is used to convert to and from python types.

I am therefore curious to know if there are even faster ways to perform the math on the cython side while minimizing python overhead passing in arguments. I am not really interested in necessarily exposing lists or array.array objects for direct access to the contents of my vectors or matrices. It would be ideal to just pass a pointer to and from python into my cython math module, but this does not seem possible as pointers are not python objects. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

Below is the code for my `Vec2` class. It is composed of two files: the first is a base `_Vec` class, and the second inherits from it as a specific `Vec2` class.

**vec.py**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random

class _Vec(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        try:
            data, = args
            data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
            cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
            vec2_check = cls_name == "Vec2" and len(data) != 2
            vec3_check = cls_name == "Vec3" and len(data) != 3
            vec4_check = cls_name == "Vec4" and len(data) != 4
            if any([vec2_check, vec3_check, vec4_check]) == True:
                raise TypeError("{0} is not a valid {1}".format(data, cls_name))
        except ValueError:
            data = np.array(args, dtype=np.float32)
        self._data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._data + other._data)
        return self.__class__(self._data + other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(other + self._data)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._data - other._data)
        return self.__class__(self._data - other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(other - self._data)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._data * other._data)
        return self.__class__(self._data * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(other * self._data)

    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__class__(self._data / other._data)
        return self.__class__(self._data / other)

    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(other / self._data)

    def __neg__(self):
        return self.__class__(-self._data)

    def __pos__(self):
        return self.__class__(+self._data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self._data, other._data)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() < other.square_length()

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() <= other.square_length()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() > other.square_length()

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() >= other.square_length()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}(data={1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.get_data())

    def __str__(self):
        return np.array_str(self._data)

    def ceil(self):
        return self.__class__(np.ceil(self._data))

    def floor(self):
        return self.__class__(np.floor(self._data))

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data.flatten().tolist()

    def inverse(self):
        return self.__class__(1.0/self._data)

    def length(self):
        return float(np.linalg.norm(self._data))

    def negate(self):
        return self.__class__(-self._data)

    def normalize(self):
        length = self.length()
        if length == 0.0:
            return self.__class__(np.zeros(self._data.shape()))
        return self.__class__(self._data/length)

    def round(self, decimal=0):
        return self.__class__(np.round(self._data, decimal))

    def square_length(self):
        return float(np.sum(np.square(self._data)))

    @classmethod
    def distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.length()

    @classmethod
    def dot(cls, a, b):
        return float(np.dot(a._data, b._data))

    @classmethod
    def equals(cls, a, b, tolerance=0.0):
        diffs = np.fabs((a - b)._data)
        pairs = zip(list(np.fabs(a._data)), list(np.fabs(b._data)))
        tolerance_calcs = [tolerance * max(1, a_val, b_val) for (a_val, b_val) in pairs]
        tests = [d <= t for (d, t) in zip(diffs, tolerance_calcs)]
        return all(tests)

    @classmethod
    def lerp(cls, a, b, t):
        return a*(1-t) + b*t

    @classmethod
    def max_components(cls, a, b):
        return cls(np.maximum(a._data, b._data))

    @classmethod
    def min_components(cls, a, b):
        return cls(np.minimum(a._data, b._data))

    @classmethod
    def random(cls, n):
        return cls(np.random.rand((n)))

    @classmethod
    def square_distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.square_length()
```

`vec2.py`

```
from vec import _Vec
from vec3 import Vec3
from vec4 import Vec4
import math
import numpy as np
import random

class Vec2(_Vec):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return float(self._data[0])

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._data[0] = float(value)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return float(self._data[1])

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._data[1] = float(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vec2(x={0}, y={1})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def transform_mat2(self, a):
        prod = np.dot(a._data.T, self._data.T).T
        return Vec2(prod)

    def transform_mat3(self, a):
        v3 = Vec3(self.get_data() + [1])
        prod = np.dot(a._data.T, v3._data.T).T
        return Vec2(prod[0:2])

    def transform_mat4(self, a):
        v4 = Vec4(self.get_data() + [0, 1])
        prod = np.dot(a._data.T, v4._data.T).T
        return Vec2(prod[0:2])

    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        return super(Vec2, cls).random(2)
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

As kazemakase pointed out, some of the values in `main.py` were integers. Defining everything as floating point by appending a .0, I got the following times instead:

```
<function pyadd at 0x0000000002FF4828> 0.384000062943
<function pyadd2 at 0x0000000002FF4908> 0.332000017166
<built-in function add> 0.227999925613
<built-in function add2> 0.640000104904
<built-in function add3> 0.258999824524
<built-in function add4> 0.556999921799
<built-in function add5> 0.145999908447
<built-in function add6> 0.983999967575
<built-in function add7> 0.217000007629
<built-in function add8> 0.236000061035
<built-in function add9> 0.131000041962
```

These appear to be similar to the original times in that case 5 and 9 are faster.

---

**UPDATE 3:**

As BrenBarn pointed out, it would probably be useful to explain how I used my original python+numpy class and why I am struggling with its performance. Originally, my entire 3d game library project was in pure python, using PyOpenGL for rendering the graphics. In order to position meshes/models in my 3d world, every frame, I need to calculate a Mat4 transformation matrix that defines that object's position, rotation, and scale in the world that is then uploaded to the GPU. When I was positioning many objects (> 1000), the frame rate in my app would slow down. While temporarily disabling 3d did improve performance somewhat, my app was still lagging below 60 fps. That is when I realized that simply calculating the `Mat4` matrices in python was to blame. When I removed these calculations and just drew all of my 3d objects at the origin, performance went back up.

Wondering then if ALL of my math3d library was slow, I thought I would start benchmarking all of these classes. I did the following benchmark for my `Vec2` class's add function as it was the simplest and computationally cheapest function to test:

```
import time
from vec2 import Vec2

def add(a, b):
    out = a + b
    return out

def test(n, func, param_list):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        func(*param_list)
    end = time.time()
    print func, end-start

test(1000000, add, [Vec2([1.0, 2.0]), Vec2([3.0, 4.0])])
#<function add at 0x00000000041B1CF8> 2.81699991226 (using the real def add(a, b) function)
#<function add at 0x000000000362CCF8> 0.168999910355 (just passing in values to def add(a, b): pass)
```

Those comments showed the times I had got just for adding two `Vec2` together. From that, I concluded that the math was slow, that there was significant python function call + class overhead, and that this was a performance bottleneck to consider in my 3d library. I hope this provides some rationale for this question.

---

**Update 4:**

What Paul Cornelius said about incurring the penalty of translation from python to cython only once got me thinking: why not just fetch a "pointer" to a `float *` object whenever I create a "Vec2 object"? Then, I can just pass in pointers for future math operations, cython can dereference those pointers to get the actual data, and the math operation can be performed. The result of that is the following code:

**main.py**

```
import time
import array
import math3d.vec2 as vec2

def make_list(a, b):
    out = [a, b]

def test(n, func, param_list):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        func(*param_list)
    end = time.time()
    print func, end-start

test(1000000, vec2.create, [1, 2])
test(1000000, make_list, [1, 2])
a = vec2.create(1, 2)
#b = vec2.get_data(a)
b = vec2.create(3, 4)
c = vec2.create(0, 0)
test(1000000, vec2.add, [c, a, b])
test(1000000, vec2.add2, [[0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
print vec2.get_data(c)
```

**vec2.pyx**

```
def add(uintptr_t out, uintptr_t a, uintptr_t b):
    cdef float *a_data = <float *>a
    cdef float *b_data = <float *>b
    cdef float *out_data = <float *>out
    out_data[0] = a_data[0] + b_data[0]
    out_data[1] = a_data[1] + b_data[1]

def create(float x, float y):
    cdef float* a = <float *>malloc(sizeof(float))
    a[:] = [x, y]
    cdef uintptr_t u_ptr = <uintptr_t> a
    return u_ptr

def get_data(uintptr_t u_ptr):
    cdef float *b = <float *>u_ptr
    return b[0], b[1]

def add2(out, a, b):
    out[0] = a[0] + b[0]
    out[1] = a[1] + b[1]
    return out
```

**Timing Results**

```
<built-in function create> 0.19000005722
<function make_list at 0x0000000002994828> 0.269999980927
<built-in function add> 0.111000061035
<built-in function add2> 0.141999959946
(4.0, 6.0)
```

Of course, handling `uintptr_t` integers in python is pretty unsafe, as they could mistakenly be added together on the python side with the `+` operator. Also, it is unclear if the slight performance benefit of this (0.03 seconds for 1 million operations) is really worth it.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll be able to write a math library from scratch that will be faster than numpy.  You might be better off showing the "python+numpy classes" you were using and trying to improve those, assuming they are some sort of wrapper around numpy objects.

Comment: @BrenBarn I included my original "python+numpy classes" implementation for my `Vec2` class. Hope this helps!

Comment: You pass lists with integers to some of the `addx` functions. I guess cases 5 and 9 are faster because they perform integer addition instead of floating point operations.

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question in which you show the simplest possible example of your custom classes, show how you are trying to use them, and explain why you think they are a performance bottleneck.  At a guess, from the code you posted, it looks like you're setting up convenience methods/properties in your Python class.  If you use those a lot, it will be slower than using the numpy objects directly.

Comment: @kazemakase I updated the question to include the floating point times. The results still look similar, despite avoiding integer addition.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Interesting. I guess then the differences may be caused by type checking/conversion during the function calls. (Out of curiosity you could try to remove the actual `out=a+b` code and time empty functions.) Note that it is unlikely that your approach will give you very good performance anyway. The `add` functions are very short and you still call them individually from Python which causes much overhead. To get most out of Cython you should try to stay as long as possible inside compiled code without calling back to Python.

Comment: @kazemakase Removing the parts of the bodies of each of the functions that was performing the addition (leaving in only cdef lines), I saw that all of the times went down (of course). However, now  `add`, `add3`, `add5`, `add7`, `add8`, and `add9` are roughly identical at about 0.09 seconds. I thought at least typing the arguments would make some significant difference. And yes, I would like to stay within Cython as long as possible, but that might be tough to accomplish, especially if I need to manipulate game models/objects from the python side every frame in my game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython's strength is arithmetic operations on basic C data types (ints, floats, doubles) and arrays of those.  The only arithmetic operation in your code is two simple additions.  The rest is data type conversions and array element access.  Those operations will certainly dominate, as your timing results indicate.  Every time you execute a function call from Python to Cython, there is type checking and conversion overhead.  You need to do enough number crunching on the Cython side of this barrier to make it worthwhile.

This is not a good use case for Cython.

Is adding a lot of two-element lists really the bottleneck in your application?  If it is, you should consider storing all the data in Cython variables, incurring the penalty of translation only once.  Move data to the Python side only when you have to.  If it isn't, you need to create a more realistic test.

My experience is that Cython can usually match or even outperform numpy, although it make take some effort to optimize.  (numpy/scipy of course has the "slight" advantage of offering more functionality than I could create in a hundred lifetimes).  But the same process of converting Python to C data types must occur there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just added some rationale for my performance concerns to the question (see `Update 3`). While adding lots of two-element lists is not the exactly bottleneck in my code, it is similar to the real bottleneck, which is multiplying lots of 4x4 matrices together :) I am wondering how I can go about moving all data from the Python side only one time if positions, rotations, and scales of 3d models can change in real time, possibly on a per frame basis.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon: With regard to your update 3, you shouldn't conclude from that that "the math is slow".  What is slow is using the `+` operator on your `Vec2` objects, which are Python objects and involve overhead on every method call (and you seem to be doing quite a few).  Also, your `__add__` creates a whole new Vec2 instance for every operation; that is also pretty slow.  I think your overall issue is rather too broad for this site.  It may help to profile your code and look at the number of calls to each function/method to get a sense for how much "churn" is going on.

Comment: @BrenBarn You are most likely right that creating the new `Vec2` instances for each addition was the slow part. I did not realize that the `+` operator has overhead as well! I will have to play around and try removing all of these convenience methods/properties. In the meantime, I made a cython method using pointers that is even faster than everything I presented so far (`Update 4`). However, there are some caveats to this and, like you said, I am not even sure if it is worth it without more profiling.

Comment: I just read your rationale for tackling this problem (update3).  You say "simply calculating the Mat4 matrices in python was to blame."  It seems to me that is not what you are modeling in your performance profiling.  You're creating and adding together two-element vectors (lists), and expecting that you will thereby get some insight into the problem of the Mat4 matrices. Are you sure that's a valid thing to do?  You've haven't shown the code to calculate the matrices, so we can't give any ideas about that.